# xsl:element stored as variable?

Tags: xslt, element

Can you store an element name as a variable to be called at a later date?

For example :

```
<xsl:variable name="element">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Argument1">strong</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="Argument2">em</xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="{$element}">
            <a href="{$url}">
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:element>
```

So based on a predefined argument, the element to be wrapped around the anchor tag has either to be `<strong>` or `<em>`.

Or am i approaching this wrong?

Going the long way round and duplicating the anchor tag inside a choose when statement for each argument doesn't seem to work.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Yes, that sort of approach is valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think your posted sample should work. With XSLT 2.0 you could even do `<xsl:element name="{if (Argument1) then 'strong' else if (Argument2) then 'em' else ()}">`.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is completely valid.

Alternatively, one could use two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="someElement[Argument1]">
 <strong>
   <a href="{$url}">                 
     <xsl:value-of select="title"/>             
   </a>  
 </strong>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="someElement[Argument2]">
 <em>
   <a href="{$url}">                 
     <xsl:value-of select="title"/>             
   </a>  
 </em>
</xsl:template>
```

It can be argued that the second approach is more declarative, flexible and maintainable.